# Getting NullPointerException when trying to start tomcat server for guacamole

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tomcat8, guacamole

I am trying to run the default guacamole package from Raspbian (bullseye), which installs tomcat8, but I am only getting a 404 error when trying to access it via apache. Looking in the error log of the tomcat server (/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2022-01-12.log) shows the following error message on startup/restart:

```
12-Jan-2022 23:23:49.934 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/guacamole]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:373)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

12-Jan-2022 23:23:49.959 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor [/etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/guacamole.xml]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/guacamole]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I am not sure what's actually wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

guacamole.xml contains the following (requested in the comments):

```
<Context path="/guacamole" docBase="/usr/share/guacamole/guacamole">
 <Resources allowLinking="true" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Are you able to show `guacamole.xml`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I added the contents of guacamole.xml to the original question above.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to try and run it as a Docker container. That way, it doesn't depend on your host's files, settings, or OS. https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that. Installing Docker on raspbian also seems to be non-trivial.